# I want to know how to open URL in existing browser window in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium

I am working on selenium web driver. I want to open existing browser window via selenium script(Java).

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in method in Selenium that supports this feature directly. However, you can try the following:

```
driver.get("link");
driver.find_element_by_link_text('new link name').click().switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0]);
```

Just switch to handle for self.You can also try storing handles in variables if you like.

The whole post can be found [here](https://seleniumwithjavapython.wordpress.com/selenium-with-python/switching-between-windows-and-alerts/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it can't work for me.It can't switch to handle for itself.

Comment: handle to self switching to the parent window itself which I wrote driver.window_handles[0]

Comment: Try it also switch_to.window(window_handles[0]); or write switch_to.window in new line using a variable.